# Trigger calling a Stored Procedure

Tags: database, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

I couldn't get the output also couldn't find the problem.

Question:

```
Table : rent_info(cust_id,date_out,date_due_in,date_returned,fine)
```

This table is for a book rental one. At first while inserting I have to give cust_id,date_out(date when book is issued),date_due_in(which is 7 days after issue date). When the book is returned a trigger is used to insert data into rent_info table.

I have to give the date_returned. In trigger I have to calculate the fine which is 10$ for every days elapsed.

For returning I wrote a procedure that **updates** the table and inserts the return date. Then a trigger is created( a row-level trigger that checks for updates how much fine is to be paid). And as a last statement the the calculated fine is **updated** to the table.

The problem is that I could generate the fine amount but the update statement given to update the fine gives me a "**table mutating error**".

Can you please tell me where I went wrong. Sorry for not posting the code. I couldn't get the code from lab. If this information is not enough I could try it in my system and post it here later.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133705/solving-the-mutating-table-problem-in-oracle-sql-produces-a-deadlock/5137951#5137951) which explains how mutating table errors can be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code it's a bit tricky to guess how you tried to solve this problem, but it sounds like you have written an UPDATE statement to update the current row from within a row-level trigger.

That is impossible. You can't UPDATE a row that's in the process of being updated.

You can update the calculated fine by changing the value of ":new.fine" inside the trigger.

Comment: Yes - and make sure the trigger is a BEFORE UPDATE trigger with the FOR EACH ROW option.