# How do i Solve Oracle Mutation Error from TRIGGER

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, mutation

I Have Two Tables; `TBL_EMPDETAILS (empdetails_id, EMP_SALARY) and TBL_SERVICE (empdetails_id, Salary, Date_Appointed)`. The idea is that when i update the tbl_service (which basically is salary history) it should update `TBL_EMPDETAILS` to the most recent Salary.

I've created a `TRIGGER`  But i keep getting  `MUTATION ERROR`. From my research i have seen recommended compound triggers but i am unsure. I also tried pragma autonomous_transaction; befor the bgin statement but encountered "DEADLOCK ERROR"

```
create or replace trigger Update_Salary  
   before insert or update on "TBL_SERVICE" 
   for each row 
declare
x number ;
y number ;
z date ;
m date;


begin 
x := :NEW."SALARY";
y  := :NEW."EMPDETAILS_ID";
z := :NEW."DATE_APPOINTED";
Select max(DATE_APPOINTED) 
into m From TBL_SERVICE Where Empdetails_id = y ;
IF  z >= m 
THEN
update tbl_empdetails Set EMP_SALARY = x Where Empdetails_id = y ;
End If;
commit;
end;
```

I Expect that when i add a row to the TBL_SERVICE for eg. (empdetails_id, Salary, Date_Appointed) = (100, $500 , 20-Jul-2019) it should update the TBL_EMPDETAILS (empdetails_id, EMP_SALARY) to (100, $500)

Mutation Error -ORA-04091
Deadlock Error -ORA-00060

So i Think the COMPOUND TRIGGER LOOKS LIKE THE ROUTE TO GO... I TRIED CODE BELOW BUT IM STILL MISSING SOMETHING :(

```
create or replace TRIGGER "RDC_HR".Update_Salary  
  FOR UPDATE OR INSERT ON "RDC_HR"."TBL_SERVICE" 
  COMPOUND TRIGGER 

  m date ;

    AFTER EACH ROW IS
     begin 
      Select max(DATE_APPOINTED) into m From TBL_SERVICE 
      Where Empdetails_id = :NEW."EMPDETAILS_ID" ;
    END AFTER EACH ROW;

    AFTER STATEMENT IS
     BEGIN

    IF  (:NEW."DATE_APPOINTED") >= m   THEN
    update tbl_empdetails Set EMP_SALARY = :NEW."SALARY" 
    Where Empdetails_id = :NEW."EMPDETAILS_ID" ;
    End If; 
   END AFTER STATEMENT;

   end Update_Salary;
```

Comment: Triggers are evil.  Move the logic to a procedure and call that from your app.  Also you should never be doing a commit in a trigger.

Comment: See the answer here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133705/solving-the-mutating-table-problem-in-oracle-sql-produces-a-deadlock)

Comment: Does `tbl_empdetails` have a trigger on it or are there other triggers on `tbl_service`?

Comment: The only other triggers on both tables are those for the ID sequence

Comment: The new version of the trigger won't work. The problem is that you cannot look at the base table in a row-level trigger. Imagine that you execute an update that modifies 50 rows in the table--Oracle will fire the row-level trigger fifty times, but if you were allowed to query the base table you might see partial work done (e.g. in your `max(DATE_APPOINTED)` query), and this would be ambiguous. Therefore, Oracle doesn't allow you to execute queries on the base table.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few basic issues with the trigger as shown.
First, it contains a `COMMIT`. There shouldn't be a `COMMIT` in a trigger, since the transaction is still in flight.

The larger problem is that you are accessing the table on which the trigger was created within the trigger:

```
Select max(DATE_APPOINTED) 
into m From TBL_SERVICE Where Empdetails_id = y ;
```

A row-level trigger cannot query or modify the base table. This is what is causing the mutating table error.

There are a few approaches to handle this.

If you want to use a trigger, you will need to defer the part that queries the base table to a time after the row-level trigger is complete.
This is done using a *statement-level* trigger or a *compound* trigger.

A row-level trigger can communicate "work to do" by storing state in a variable in a package, a following statement-level trigger can then inspect the package variables and do work based on the content.

The compound trigger mechanism is a way of putting the row and statement triggers in one code unit, along with the package bits. It is a way of writing the whole thing with one chunk of code (compound trigger) rather than three (row trigger, package, statement trigger).

Here is a detailed writeup of using Compound Triggers: [Get rid of mutating table trigger errors with the compound trigger](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html)

As mentioned, moving the code out of triggers and into a stored procedure is certainly an option.

Comment: Tad Harrison, i think this is the way to go....but still abit uncertain on the syntax.

Comment: See my note about the newer version of the trigger. You can't query a base table in a row-level trigger. The update or insert to the base table happens all at once, so you can only do the `MAX` query after the row-level work is all done. This can be done by keeping a list of touched primary keys in the row-level part of a compound trigger, then going through that list in the statement-level part, executing post-processing for each PK in the list.